# java.sql.SQLException: Table/View 'SEQUENCE' already exists in Schema 'ADMIN'

Tags: java, exception, jpa, eclipselink, javadb

My application throws this Exception.
I am using Java DB as the back end and i am using JPA

> Internal Exception:
>   java.sql.SQLException: Table/View
>   'POCKETMONEY' already exists in Schema
>   'APP'. Error Code: 30000 Call: CREATE
>   TABLE APP.POCKETMONEY (ID INTEGER NOT
>   NULL, DateofSpending DATE, DESCRIPTION
>   VARCHAR(255), AMOUNT INTEGER, PRIMARY
>   KEY (ID)) Query: DataModifyQuery()
>
> Internal Exception:
>   java.sql.SQLException: Table/View
>   'SEQUENCE' already exists in Schema
>   'ADMIN'. Error Code: 30000 Call:
>   CREATE TABLE SEQUENCE (SEQ_NAME
>   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, SEQ_COUNT
>   DECIMAL, PRIMARY KEY (SEQ_NAME))
>   Query: DataModifyQuery()

Here is my JPA code

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package mymoney;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

/**
 *
 * @author sugan
 */
@Entity
@Table(schema = "APP")
public class pocketMoney implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    private int id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "DateofSpending")
    private Date dos;
    private String description;
    private int amount;

    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Date getDos() {
        return dos;
    }

    public void setDos(Date dos) {
        this.dos = dos;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (int) id;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof pocketMoney)) {
            return false;
        }
        pocketMoney other = (pocketMoney) object;
        if (this.id != other.id) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "mymoney.pocketMoney[id=" + id + "]";
    }
}
```

Persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="myMoneyPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>mymoney.pocketMoney</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="adminadmin"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="admin"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:pocketmoney;create=true"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Without seeing the code, which causes the error, I can just translate the error message. It seems your code is trying to creat tables, which already exist in your database...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever JPA provider you're using, I suspect that it is configured to generate and export the database  objects corresponding to your mappings... and those already exist.

Depending on your configuration, on the JPA provider, on the exact message (EclipseLink logs such messages as warning AFAIK), this might be just normal or a "configuration mistake".

If you want more details, please tell us what provider you're using and show your `persistence.xml`.

**Update:** As suspected, you are using EclipseLink and these message are "normal" (they are logged as warning if you look closely at the message IIRC)